# Get a list of groups that Azure AD user belongs to in claims

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am authenticating users of my web api against Azure Active Directory.
Now I want to get a list of groups that this user belongs.

I changed application manifest to include

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "All",
```

but all this does is to add claim hasGroups but no group names.

I granted all (8) Delegated Permissions to Windows Azure Active Directory for my app in the portal.

Comment: The "hasGroups" claim gets added when the user is part of more than 5 groups, even though that doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. 5 or fewer and you'll get a handful of "groups" claims with the object id of the group.

Answer (score 9):

I've done exactly this.

Let's call my Azure AD appication "AD-App".

**AD-App**

*Permissions to other applications is set to;*

Windows Azure Active Directory.

*Application Permissions: 0.*

*Delegated Permissions 2* ("Read directory data", "Sign in and read user profile".

*Manifest* has the following setting:

"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"

**Backend API**

The following is my method to return the users groups. Either you send in the users id, if not it uses the id from claims. Id meaning "objectIdentifier".

```
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetGroupMembershipsByObjectId(string id = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        IList<string> groupMembership = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = ActiveDirectoryClient;
            IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId == id).ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;
            var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)user;

            IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync().Result;
            do
            {
                List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
                foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects)
                {
                    if (directoryObject is Group)
                    {
                        var group = directoryObject as Group;
                        groupMembership.Add(group.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
                pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
            } while (pagedCollection != null);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(e);
            throw e;
        }

        return groupMembership;
    }
```

I can't tell you wether this is done by best practice or not, but it works for me.

Comment: An important note for any readers of this: the Backend API method as it's written does not retrieve transitive group memberships. The former method via AD portal configuration does.

Comment: Thanks Worked for me :-)

Comment: It would be nice if you included the necessary namespaces in the above example.

Comment: @LarryBud yeah sorry about that, I will try to remember to do that another time. Not sure I can find this project again, but if I do I'll update my answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas, when you said the above method is the Backend API method, do you mean you run it in Azure somehow (I'm new to Azure, so got a lot to learn)? Or is it run in something like a MVC controller?

Comment: @Rod - Holy moly, this is so long ago I can't say for sure! But, I do believe it was a WebAPI project running as a Azure Web App at the time :)  Hope it helps!

Comment: Talking about namespaces, just to let you know in order to use that piece of code you have to install the following NUGET Package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient

Comment: `ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = ActiveDirectoryClient` this line doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what we did in a project:

Sign in to https://portal.azure.com and click on `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> `<YOUR_APP>` -> `Manifest` and set `groupMembershipClaims` to `7`. You can read more about this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest

You can then access the user groups like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CurrentUserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("groups")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ClaimsViewModel>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public IActionResult Groups()
    {
        return Ok(User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "groups").Select(c => new ClaimsViewModel() { Type = c.Type, Value = c.Value }));
    }
}

public class ClaimsViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Sample respons with fake Object IDs:

```
[{"type":"groups","value":"12fef9e0-4b73-425d-91b7-30c027aa4945"},{"type":"groups","value":"12fef9e0-4b73-425d-91b7-30c027aa4946"},{"type":"groups","value":"12fef9e0-4b73-425d-91b7-30c027aa4947"},{"type":"groups","value":"12fef9e0-4b73-425d-91b7-30c027aa4948"},{"type":"groups","value":"12fef9e0-4b73-425d-91b7-30c027aa4949"}]
```

Given these IDs you can then identify the groups in AD.

Comment: Big caveat here: if the user is in more than 5 groups, they will only get the "hasGroups" claim that the OP mentions "to limit token size." Ran into this unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

If a user has more than 150 groups, only the link to Graph API in a calim like "graph:link" is returned and not the groups. It is done for performance reasons. You then need to call Graph API (MS Graph API - newest, or AD Graph API - older) to iterated through all groups.

Answer (score 0):

What permissions did you grant to your app? You need to explicitly request the ability to read groups (see group.read.all in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes). As of today, those permissions can only be consented by an administrator.

Comment: I added info about added permissions