# How can I get Job Title or Department from an Azure AD authenticated user in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure, webforms, azure-active-directory

I have a web application that pre-populates a form with the users info where applicable. For populating the users name, I have used the `ClaimsPrincipal` to return the info as below:

```vb
    Private Sub WebApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim cp As ClaimsPrincipal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current
        txtName.Text = cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value & " " & cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value
    End Sub
```

I also need to return the users Job Title and Department. How can I access the Azure AD Profile in code behind? I've looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838581/get-job-info-job-title-department-and-manager-id-from-azure-ad-in-claims) and it looks as if it's pointing towards the Graph API, but am not sure if this would allow me to access it in the Code Behind or how I can even do this.

Comment: The exact way are: `1. First you have to obtain token then`  `2. Call Grpah API`. You could execute this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,jobTitle,department` that would fetch your required information. Feel free to ask further query if you have any thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MdFaridUddinKiron - how can I do this in code behind with the API response? I want to place the returned value into an `<asp:TextBox>`.

Comment: Yes you can call that API, and bind that response to a class property then bind to your textbox. I guess you are using aspx web form.